# Should I start a new journey?

Tags: work-environment, career-development, careers, motivation, first-job

Almost a year after graduating, I work for a large company. I am highly motivated and passionate about my current job. I have never had any experience as a product manager, but I feel that I have been doing this all my life.

### A brief overview about me

- Somehow everything is easily solvable for me with no help from anyone
- Hungry for knowledge and feedback
- I enjoy reading non-fiction books and technical papers
- quick learner
- identify risks and make decisions faster than others

**Other observation I've noticed in my company:**

- I outperform every other young professional and got attention from other countries
- Top Management spoke about me at an onboarding event
- my vision of how our department or any position will work in the future was copied from me. Which is not bad, I believe in the canvas strategy.
- I was tested on Hi-Po and Hi-Per, but I did not receive the result
- I think differently than others and always want to see the big picture
- I get lots of praise and compliments

**Problems:**

- In my current department nobody can guide me or advise me on a professional level (mentor). This is my first job and I would like to have a mentor from whom I can learn.
- I always get only positive feedback
- To find other colleagues at my level of interest and motivation

I am afraid of rusting and that the company will only stop me for something better in the future. The work contract is really good, with low working hours and above average salary. They have given me a lot of freedom to develop myself. Now I have a good start-up idea that I'm already working on my weekend and I'd like to try it out, but somehow I feel that it's still too early and I should wait for it.

What would be your advice?

Comment: "I feel that it's still too early and I should wait for it." Wait for what? If you're going to start a startup, you better have some money ahead of you.

Comment: "Should I" questions are generally off topic. This is not a personal guidance forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No logical reason to quit if you are paid well and feel respected by your employer. Don't risk losing your job during this difficult and uncertain time. If you have bigger dreams and a clear plan to establish your own business then you can leave to fulfil your dream.

Answer (score 1):

The people in the front cannot really be helped. Being faster than the fastest? More intelligent than the most intelligent?

Just a simple example: from whom could Einstein, or Newton, learn? They defined their own challenges, and made their best to solve those challenges.

Since you admit that there is no one there good enough to help you, why do you expect someone to give you "lessons" / coaching?

I see 2 options:

- become the coach yourself, for your colleagues; eventually change your career to become a trainer;
- find another job which can satisfy your needs.